# Can anyone explain to me in some detail why the output of this code is 0

Tags: python

i was testing my self with python coding and there is one code that i could not understand:

```
def func(x, ans):
   if(x==0):
      return 0
   else: 
      return func(x-1, x+ans) 
print(func(2,0))
```

why the output is zero ?

Answer (score 1):

Because your function runs a recursion, where the only thing it returns is 0.

We can step through your program like this;

1. step 1, `x == 2`, `ans == 0`
2. `x` is not 0
3. so we go into else condition
4. `x` is decremented by 1 and ans is incremented by 1
5. step 2, `x == 1`, `ans == 1`
6. `x` is not 0
7. so we go into else condition
8. `x` is decremented by 1 and ans is incremented by 1
9. step 3, `x == 0`, `ans == 2`
10. `x` is 0
11. so we `return 0`

done

Answer (score 0):

This function is recursive.

Try adding print statements everywhere to understand it:

```
def func(x, ans):
   print('Currently running func for ' + str([x, ans]))
   if(x==0):
      return 0, ans  # also returning ans for clarity
   else:
      print('x was not 0, i will now run func for ' + str([x-1, x+ans]))
      return func(x-1, x+ans)
func(2,0)
```

It should make the recursivity clearer

Answer (score 0):

Consider the expansion of the print statement's arguement:

```
    print( func(2,0) -> func(1, 2) -> func(0, 3) -> 0)
```

The final call to `func()` will return `0`, and so this will be the singlular value printed.

What you are likely attempting to do is moreso like:

```
def func(x, ans):
   print(x, ans)
   if(x==0):
      return 0
   else:
      return func(x-1, x+ans)
func(2,0)
```

In this example, the values are printed at every iteration, and so more than the final `0` are shown.